# xarray.open_dataset will not open all netcdf files in one folder

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray

I have a folder containing many netcdf files for individual station data (about 8,000 files total). When I attempt to read in all of these files using xarray.open_mfdataset, I get an error that reads "OSError: no files to open." I am using the code below:

```
station_data = xr.open_mfdataset('~/Data/station_data/all_stations/*.nc')
```

In contrast, I do not have any issue opening individual station data (one file) using xarray.open_dataset, as below:

```
station1 = xr.open_dataset('~/Data/station_data/all_stations/hadisd.3.1.0.2019f_19310101-20200101_010010-99999.nc')
```

I have been playing with other ways to express the path, with no luck. Any suggestions on how to properly read in all station data at once are appreciated!

Comment: Strange.. Does it work if you manually populate a list of files, i.e. `import glob; files=glob.glob('/path/to/*.nc'); f = xr.open_mfdataset(files)`? If not, does it work for smaller sub-sets, e.g. `f = xr.open_mfdataset(files[:10])`?